# Getting element names using XPath/XQuery

Tags: xpath, xquery

having the following XML sample document, I need to issue an XPath/XQuery expression to get the element names for every children of a CD element.

```
<CD>
  <TITLE>Empire Burlesque</TITLE>
  <ARTIST>Bob Dylan</ARTIST>
  <COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY>
  <COMPANY>Columbia</COMPANY>
  <PRICE>10.90</PRICE>
  <YEAR>1985</YEAR>
</CD>
```

So I need the query to return TITLE, ARTIST, COUNTRY, COUNTRY, PRICE, YEAR , any one can help please?
thanks

Comment: Your terminology doesn't match your sample. `<TITLE>`, etc are child elements of `<CD>`, not attributes.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
/CD/*/name()
```

(padded out because StackOverflow doesn't like short answers)

Comment: what if we wanted to return CD?
just name()?  ./name() returns blank...trying to get the root node's name

Comment: name(/*) - the outermost element is not the "root node" in the XPath data model; it has a parent which is called the root node in XPath 1.0, or the document node in XPath 2.0.

Comment: javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: Unknown nodetype: name .. it is not working ..

Comment: The expression requires XPath 2.0+ or XQuery 1.0+, it won't work in XPath 1.0.

Answer (score -1):

Try `/\*/name()`
e.g. for Oracle use

```
XMLCast(XMLQuery('/*/name()' PASSING db_some_field_name RETURNING CONTENT) AS VARCHAR2(4000))
```